# Is there a #define _KEYWORD_ in arduino.h to check against?

Tags: arduino, constants

I would prefer to use standard Arduino API's if they are available. I need a way to check if `arduino.h` is present. If it is not available (i.e. executing code on BeagleBone Black), then I can use my own functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif
```

Taken from: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ReleaseNotes [internals]